# Как в WebClient на C# прочитать куку?

Tags: c#, http, webclient

Приложение на C# скачивает файл

```
string link = @"http://localhost:2613/siteapi/getfile"; 
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, "accesscode=123456");
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), @"c:\Download\" + "file.txt");
```

Сервер ответит другой кукой и отдаст файл.
Как можно прочитать куку в респонсе WebClient ?

Answer (score 2):

Если хотите просто прочитать попробуйте

```
string cookie=webClient.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"];
```

Answer (score -3):

Для запросов к одному сайту можно использовать такое:

```vb
Private CookieContainer As New CookieContainer
Private CookieUri As New Uri("http://example.com")

Public ReadOnly Property CookieHeader As String
  Get
    Return CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(CookieUri)
  End Get
End Property
```

```vb
Using WC As New WebClient
  With WC
    .Headers("Cookie") = CookieHeader
    Using ResponseStream As Stream = Await .OpenReadTaskAsync(Url)
      ' Somehow process the stream
    End Using
    Dim SetCookie As String = .ResponseHeaders("Set-Cookie")
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(SetCookie) Then CookieContainer.SetCookies(CookieUri, SetCookie)
  End With
End Using
```

То же на C#:

```cs
private CookieContainer CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
private Uri CookieUri = new Uri("http://example.com");

public string CookieHeader =>
    CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(CookieUri);
```

```cs
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers("Cookie") = CookieHeader;
    using (var ResponseStream = await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync(Url))
    {
        // Somehow process the stream
    }
    var SetCookie = wc.ResponseHeaders("Set-Cookie");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SetCookie)) CookieContainer.SetCookies(CookieUri, SetCookie);
}
```

Comment: языком не ошиблись?

Comment: @tCode, мне лень переписывать на другой. Они одинаковые, на вопрос я ответил.

Comment: @Qwertiy лень переписывать, так хоть оговорку бы сделали в ответе.

Comment: @Anatol, какую именно?