# Не обновляется html на странице

Tags: c#

Всем привет) Хочу на стим маркете спарсить в табличку ссылки предметов. Проблема в том что если перейти [здесь](http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?appid=570#p1_popular_desc) на вторую страничку то html будет показывать первой. Я тестил очень много раз, причем ctrl+u показывал всегда один и тот же html, а ctrl+shift+i менял значения. В голову пришла идея что может можно все предметы на 1 страничку сделать? Поможет кто? Вот как я отправляю запрос.

```
Uri sites = new Uri(url);

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sites);
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(MyProxyHostString, MyProxyPort);
req.Proxy = myproxy;
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
req.CookieContainer = GetUriCookieContainer(sites);
```

Comment: Там на ajax-запросах переход по страницам.

Comment: Можно как то реализовать в c#?

Comment: Можно всё. Бери [Fiddler](//www.telerik.com/fiddler), смотри посылаемые запросы и делай так же. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584116/178988